# Programmatically get a PNG for a unicode emoji

Tags: png, emoji, python-unicode

In python I have a combined emoji like this: `"" + "\u200D" + ""` which is normally represented as https://emojipedia.org/male-mechanic/. I want to get a PNG version to use as a plot point (in matplotlib, if that helps). Is there any official or unofficial place where I can convert unicode versions of emojis into PNG equivalents?

Comment: Resources and library (etc.) recommendations are off topic on Stack Overflow. But strangely enough, that very page that you point to lists various PNG versions of your emoji.

Comment: Thanks. I'm unsure how to get those programmatically, though?

Comment: Also, sorry for the OT, if that's a problem.

Comment: Do you *need* to get them automatically? Surely you know which one(s) you want to use? Then right-click and save the images using your browser. Unless your use case is much more complicated than what you describe.

Comment: I have (say) 10,000 points, and want to allocate a different randomly picked emoji from a set for each point. So yes, I guess programmatic is best (the points are individual people plotted in a large simulated family-tree)

Answer (score 4):

For anyone else looking for an answer, at the moment I'm using the PNGs from https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html, with a hack that parses the web page, like this

```
class EmojiConverter:
    def __init__(self):
        import requests
        import re
        self.data = requests.get('https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html').text
    def to_base64_png(self, emoji, version=0):
        """For different versions, you can set version = 0 for , """
        html_search_string = r"<img alt='{}' class='imga' src='data:image/png;base64,([^']+)'>" #'
        matchlist = re.findall(html_search_string.format(emoji), self.data)
        return matchlist[version]

e = EmojiConverter()
b64 = e.to_base64_png(""+"\u200D" + "")
```

Comment: Is there a way to do the opposite of this? I have one ```.png``` file for each emoji which I have scraped from FB. Is there a way to convert these ```.png``` emojis into string format?

Comment: That sounds hard in general. However, when scraping, could you save the unicode equivalent in  the PNG metadata?

Comment: I'm not quite sure. They're not always PNGs I guess, for example, [this](https://scontent-sin6-4.xx.fbcdn.net/m1/v/t6/An-tsvy1nZCAfjJDq_e9hwhgJ_ouDg6GOHdVQtc31Lh3B13GEFJ0N3wRI6j2_Lz8icCyU4RkVsKbJckG5NMDv5TxxWie8OqB_kcvCNizVjn7sw.png?ccb=9-4&oh=befdda3b011a28565325dd7387638e2f&oe=60FC9D2D). I have found an alternate way to do this but that requires me to send one extra request for every post I want to scrape.  There is no metadata as far as I can see. Not in the form of the ```alt``` attribute of tags at least.